# How to set image using Kingfisher when image url did not change but image changed

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

How to retrieve correct image using Kingfisher when image url did not change but image changed such as Twitter or GitHub.

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) has a option [SDWebImageRefreshCached] to solve the problem.

```
   /**
     * Even if the image is cached, respect the HTTP response cache control, and refresh the image from remote location if needed.
     * The disk caching will be handled by NSURLCache instead of SDWebImage leading to slight performance degradation.
     * This option helps deal with images changing behind the same request URL, e.g. Facebook graph api profile pics.
     * If a cached image is refreshed, the completion block is called once with the cached image and again with the final image.
     *
     * Use this flag only if you can't make your URLs static with embedded cache busting parameter.
     */
    SDWebImageRefreshCached = 1 << 4,
```

How to solve the problem in Kingfisher?

Answer (score 3):

[Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) has forceRefresh option to force downloading image again skiping cache

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, options: [.forceRefresh])
```

refer this [github](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/35) thread for more details

Comment: isn't forceRefresh going to download the image every time ?

Comment: Only refresh when app quite and relaunch